# insert rows using sheets on google spreadsheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am in the process of adapting the code below to insert a full row after function get emails is run. the extra row function works so i thought i would add line to the end of the getEmails. But it adds around 30 extra rows, i only need one added.

```
sheet.insertRows(2)
```

below is the getEmail code.

```
function getEmails() {
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("pollux");
 var threads = label.getThreads();
 var row = 3;
 for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
  var messages=threads[i].getMessages();
        for (var m=0; m < messages.length; m++) {   
          sheet.getRange(row,1).setValue(messages[m].getPlainBody());
     row++;
      sheet.insertRows(2);
```

some helpful suggestions would be great.

Cheers Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line    sheet.insertRows(2);
and place outside this for loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
```

Comment: Changed to the following but get type error cannot call method "getMesssages"  of undefined

Comment: `  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++);
  sheet.insertRows(2);{
        var messages=threads[i].getMessages();`

Answer (score 0):

Changed code to

```
function getEmails() {
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("pollux");
 var threads = label.getThreads();
 var row = 3;
 sheet.insertRows(2);
for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
   var messages=threads[i].getMessages();
   for (var m=0; m < messages.length; m++) {   
   sheet.getRange(row,1).setValue(messages[m].getPlainBody());
   row++;
```

now adds line and moves row down as 1 as i need.